# How to find a reset rupture in the counter and fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a process that increases several counters automatically.
However, some external actions, i.e. human interaction resets these counters.
and after some time the counters are aligned back.

From data perspective, I am left with counters that have a rupture at a specific point, and I want to align them.

counters look like this:

`counter = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]`

and i want to fix them:

`counter = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

I have many columns with such counters and I was thinking of a neat way to do it by finding first the rupture and then fix it.

Comment: You mention you have many counters. Are the numeric sequences all different?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this element by element in a list, you could convert this sequence as such:

```
offset = 0                                # after a reset, save how much we're off by
for i in range(1, len(counter)):
    if counter[i] - counter[i - 1] >= 0:  # if sequence is stable or increasing, no action needed
        offset = 0                        # though if it just became so, reset the offset
    else:
        if offset == 0:                   # if this is the first out-of-order element,
            offset = value                # set the offset based on current value
        counter[i] += offset              # and update the value with the offset
```

A couple of caveats. First, this will not work properly if there are multiple resets before a return-to-form. You could probably detect this by storing the *actual* value of the last element in a variable, and checking whether there's another decrease, and updating offset accordingly.

Second, there are probably more efficient ways to do this, *especially* if you're using a structure like a pandas dataframe instead of a vanilla python list. Those aren't my area of expertise, though, so I don't know what they'd be.